# Pushing object in array

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I trying to add object into array. But when i console log got empty array. Please check i am doing anything wrong. (When i console log instead of push it working fine)

```
const fs = require("fs");
const XLSX = require("xlsx");
const axios = require('axios');

// Read the file into memory
const workbook = XLSX.readFile("excel.xlsx");

let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
// 3683
const jsonArr = [];

function addData() {
  for(let i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
    var add = worksheet[`C${i}`].v;
    axios.get('https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json', {
      params : {
        q:add,
        key:keys
      }
    }
    )
    .then(function(res) {
      // console.log(res.data.results[2].geometry);
      jsonArr.push(res.data.results[2].geometry);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
}
addData();
console.log(jsonArr);
```

Comment: most probably the requests to the server have not finished when you print the array - thus it is still empty.

Comment: then how can i resolve it. I need to create json file for this data

Comment: Read. Read, read, and read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/476

Answer (score -1):

This is a common problem if using promises. Instead, try creating the structure in `this()` and then return it, so you can then retrieve it from the chain e.g.:

```js
const result = axios.get(...).then(res => res.data.results[2].geometry);
```

and then for example add it to the outer array.

Or instead use `async/await` to ensure the request has properly finished:

```js
const result = await axios.get(...);
```